# AppleScript: Can't add text to Numbers cell

Tags: applescript, numbers

I'm trying to add text to a Numbers cell but I keep running in a -10006 error:

```
Can't set <object or data> to <object or data>.
```

Here's the relevant portion of my script.

```
set rowNum to 1
    repeat with thisObj in buildSchedule
        set rowNum to rowNum + 1
        set buildMaster to item 1 of thisObj as text
        set buildDate to item 3 of thisObj as text
        set buildStatus to item 4 of thisObj as text
        
        log class of buildMaster
        
        set value of cell rowNum of column "A" to buildMaster
        
    end repeat
```

when I run this here's the log class output and error message:

```
(*text*)

Result:
error "Numbers got an error: Can’t set cell \"A2\" to \"Sxxxxxx Sxxxxxxx\"." number -10006 from cell "A2"
```

So kind of confused as to what I

Comment: Have a look at: https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/index.html

Comment: Note I posted a link to a very helpful site for working with **AppleScript** and **Numbers** because as I see it there is not adequate information in your question to test the _code_. If you what help debugging _code_ then comfom your question to: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: LOL, you solved it without trying to solve it. My repeat was outside the end tell for the table. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.